# Assigning this pointer to rvalue reference to a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Should the following sample compile?

```
struct B;
struct A
{
  A(B*&&){}
};

struct B : A
{
  B() : A(this){}
};

int main(){}
```

On [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1v4bC9%241) with clang it compiles, but with gcc I get:

> no known conversion for argument 1 from 'B* const' to 'B*&&'

and if I add a `const` it compiles.

I would like to also point out MSVC gets it wrong too:

> cannot convert parameter 2 from 'B *const ' to 'B *&&'

so it looks like we have a bug in two compilers.

**BUGS FILED**

[MSVC bug link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781977/this-pointer-fails-to-bind-to-rvalue-reference-to-pointer)

[GCC bug link](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56701)

Comment: For info - this compiles on the Intel C++ compiler (13.1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that should compile.

It is incorrect to implement `this` as `cv T* const` (where cv is the cv-qualifiers for the function, if any, and `T` is the class type). `this` is not `const`, merely a prvalue expression of a built-in type (not modifiable).

Many people think that because you can't modify `this` it must be `const`, but as [Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) once commented long ago, a much better explanation is something like this:

```
// by the compiler
#define this (__this + 0)

// where __this is the "real" value of this
```

Here it's clear that you can't modify `this` (say, `this = nullptr`), but also clear no `const` is necessary for such an explanation. (And the value you have in your constructor is just the value of the temporary.)

Comment: Is it actually specified that we can't modify `this`? Obviously we can't when it's a prvalue, but what if we bind it to an rvalue reference and modify it through that?

Comment: Interesting, so that means [the selected answer to this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341607/so-what-is-the-type-of-this-why-is-this-not-a-lvalue) is wrong?

Comment: @sftrabbit: It's a side-effect of it being a prvalue and a built-in type. Such objects cannot be treated as lvalues (assigned to or modified in general). This doesn't apply to user-defined types because then we have operator overloading and what have you. You can invoke a member function on an rvalue, for example.

Comment: @JesseGood: Yes. I edited it. (Heh, I left a comment on that question with the same `#define this` example, almost two years ago.)

Comment: @GManNickG I've figured it out. Binding an rvalue reference to `this` will first create a temporary copy of it and then bind to that. So the original `this` pointer can't actually be affected.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Yup! Same as: `int&& x = 0;`.

Comment: @GmanNickG Yeah, I just tried `int&& x = 5; x++;` and for a moment thought I'd changed math itself. Now we shall learn to count with 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, ...

Comment: It was in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385297/whats-wrong-with-c-compared-to-other-languages#comment214413_385316 (deleted, but still readable in the quotes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference )

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Ha, nice find. :)

Answer (score 6):

I say clang is right - the code should compile. For some reason, GCC considers the `this` pointer to be `const` despite the following:

> The type of `this` in a member function of a class `X` is `X*`. If the member function is declared `const`, the type of this is `const X*`, if the member function is declared `volatile`, the type of this is `volatile X*`, and if the member function is declared `const volatile`, the type of this is `const volatile X*`.

So in this case, `this` should be a prvalue `B*` and perfectly bindable to `B*&&`. However, note that when binding `this` to an rvalue reference, the value of `this` will be copied into a temporary object and the reference will instead be bound to that. This ensures that you never actually modify the original `this` value.

> A reference to type "cv1 `T1`" is initialized by an expression of type "cv2 `T2`" as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - [...] or **the reference shall be an rvalue reference**.
>
>   - If the initializer expression
>
>     - is an xvalue, class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue and [...], or
>     - has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), [...]
>
>     then [...]
>   - **Otherwise**, a temporary of type “cv1 T1” is created and initialized from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference copy-initialization (8.5). The reference is then bound to the temporary. [...]

Comment: Maybe because you're in the constructor?

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't see a rule that says that, but still, why would that make the *pointer* `const`?

Comment: Hm, scratch that... but notice that `this` is an *expression*, not a variable. It's a prvalue.

Comment: Your argument is invalid. Gcc doesn't say that `this` is `const B*`. It says it's a `B* const` which is not the same thing! `this` is a prvalue, so `B*` and `B* const` are basically the same thing

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan That's not true. A prvalue of type `B* const` wouldn't  bind to a `B*&&`, whereas a prvalue of type `B*` would.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Be that as it may, all I am saying is that the quote you provided is irrelevant because it speaks of another const. In any case I don't think that a **prvalue** of type `B*` can be bound to `B*&&` either. I may be wrong though

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: How is the quote irrelevant?  It says what type `this` is, which conflicts with what GCC says its type is.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: It may not say explicitly "there is no const on the pointer, by the way", but it does omit it which is equivalent (and on the previous line in the standard says its a prvalue).

Comment: I forgot that there also is 3.10p4: `non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualiﬁed types`. This means a prvalue of `B*` can never be 
`const`.

Comment: @GManNickG: Maybe I am missing something, but I started to think 
Armen Tsirunyan point stands, as a `prvalue always have cv-unqualified types` as from my previous quote.

Comment: @JesseGood: I'm not sure I follow. GCC/MSVC have a bug so it's *not* a prvalue, so they can add `const`.

Comment: @JesseGood That means `this` is for sure a `B*` (not a `B* const`) and can therefore be bound to `B*&&`. GCC is saying that `this` is a `B* const`, which goes against the standard.

Comment: @GManNickG, sftrabbit: Right, it still is a bug in both compilers. I was thinking in terms of the underlying type of `this` could be `T* const` per the standard, but that is thinking of `this` as an object and not an expression which is wrong.