# return by reference from copy assignment overload

Tags: c++

I wonder, why don't we use only `this` without `*` in case of an overloaded assignment operator? If I use `this` only, it gives me a compiler error. Why we don't use `*` with `arr[i]`, or any other variables, like `return x` in the 2nd and 3rd example?

```cpp
Myclass &Myclass::operator=(const Myclass &rhs)
{
    if(this==&rhs)
        return *this;
}
```

---

```cpp
double& setValues( int i ) {
    return vals[i];   // return a reference to the ith element
}
```

---

```cpp
int& setValues(int x) {
    return x;   // return address/reference  of x
}
```

Comment: because `this` is a pointer to the current object, so if you want a reference to a object, you have to dereference it

Comment: `*x` means `x[0]`

Comment: @M.M While correct, I think that's only going to cause more confusion here

Comment: so in case if i want to return pointer (by address) , do i still need to use *this???
Myclass *Myclass::operator=(const Myclass &rhs)
{
          if(this==&rhs)
               return *this;
}

Comment: Note that example 3 looks like a bomb. It returns a reference to `x`, and `x` is a local variable.

Comment: @user4581301 you are correct  , i should make x global before it destroyed by function termination

Comment: In the given example you do **not** want to return reference to a pointer to an instance. You want to return the instance **at** the pointer.

Comment: @MooingDuck if someone is confused by `*x` and `x[0]` then now would be a good time to try and gain understanding

Comment: @user4581301 so if i want to return pointer , i will just return this because it's already pointer and the function will return the pointer address of this (object) , so if i want to use it outside function i will need to *deference it

Comment: how is this an rvalue ??? this has an address in memory for the current object???

Comment: Weird as it sounds, sometimes you do want to return a reference to a pointer just like sometimes you need to pass a reference to a pointer, but as MM pointed out above you can't return a reference to `this`. Wrong type of variable.

Comment: @logan_92 it's a strange thing, but `this` is just plain strange. If I remember correctly, the only reason `this` is a pointer is references didn't exist when `this` was added to the language.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for clarification but C++ is so weird

Comment: @M.M thank you for the clarification

Comment: @M.M *x means x[0] , do you mean *x refer to firs element of the array because the first element of the array is const pointer ???

Comment: `this` is a pointer to the instance. Think of the chaos you could cause if you returned a reference to `this` and then some <expletive deleted>er *changed where it pointed*. What would that even mean? The object you passed into the function is still where it was. Could you damage it's `this`? Probably a really good Q&A for this  already on SO. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @user4581301 ok for 1st example in my code when i return *this , this means i return the object itself (address of object??) , but if i return this => it means i just return the address that exist in this pointer. is this correct????

Comment: *i return the object itself* Yup. No address involved. A pointer is just another variable, but instead of holding a number or whatever, it holds the address of another object. If you return a pointer, you return a copy of the address. If you return a reference  to a pointer, you return the pointer and the receiver can modify where it points.

Comment: Reading on that `this` is an rvalue stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341607/so-what-is-the-type-of-this-why-is-this-not-a-lvalue , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095476/is-this-pointer-an-r-value, and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067244/type-of-this-pointer

Comment: @user4581301 so in case of *this => this will return a reference to this object in my stack. and reference is as an alias for this object. 
if i use this => it will just return an address of this pointer and this address points to the object , so if i want to access the object i will need to * pointer

Comment: thank you @user4581301   , i think i got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@logan_92: References, and pointers are a bit tricky: `House&` is a reference to a house somewhere ("That is Bob's house over there").  `House*` is a building address ("13931 Main Street").  Dereferencing a pointer is like driving to the building.

Likewise: `this` is a *pointer*. It is the *address* of a `Myclass`, it is not a `Myclass` itself.  `operator=` returned a reference to a house, so you dereference it to go to the `Myclass&`, so that you can return the reference.  It has nothing to do with being "inside the class" or "outside the class". The only difference is an address vs a reference.

One of the things you can do with pointers and addresses is get an offset. ("The house 3 down from 13931 Main Street"). The basic syntax is `*(pointer+3)`. This turns out to be *incredibly* handy, so C made a special syntax for this: `pointer[3]`.  It is a reference to the third object over from the address of `pointer`.  As a result, `this[0]` is the same as `*this`. It's 0 objects over from the address.

Comment: thank you for the answer . it cleared a lot of confusion, but i'm just new to programming so maybe i'm asking stupid questions , this[0] => it means the object itself ??? i wounder what will it return (i think it return the name of the object and because operator= return a reference to the object so it will return the address of this object)?? and also this syntax this[0] like you treat object as arrays??? so if i write this[1] what will it access???

Comment: pointers and arrays [have an interesting relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517164/why-am-i-being-told-that-an-array-is-a-pointer-what-is-the-relationship-between). For pointer `p`, `p[N]` is just a [pretty way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) of writing `*(p+N)`. So if `N` is 0, `*(p+0)`-> `*(p)`-> `*p`. So `this[0]` will be `*this`.

Comment: `p[1]` is whatever's in storage after `*p`. If you have an array, `p[1]` makes sense. If not, you've indexed outside of [the object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) (Read the link because in C++ object doesn't mean what you probably think it does) and get to experience the joys of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) first hand. This means that `this[1]` is the storage after `this` and frankly I've never delved deep enough into the corners of C++ to know if it's legal to do this even if `this` is part of an array.

Comment: [**class.this**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.this) and [**expr.prim.this**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.this) don't shed any light on that last bit. I'm going to leave this one for the language lawyers.

Comment: Interesting side note: Because `p[N]` is `*(p+N)`, you can perform some seriously deviant smurf like `N[p]` and get the same result. You'll probably never find a good reason to take advantage of this trick, and if you did it would probably fail code review. But it does show up in trick questions on exams and interviews.

Comment: `this` is just a pointer just like any other (mostly).  So the C++ language doesn't know if it's a pointer at one element or a pointer at many elements, so it allows you to write `this[0]` just the same as `*this`. They're exactly the same, they're both a reference to the pointed-at object.   A reference _isn't_ quite an address, it's merely a reference to an object somewhere. In many cases, the compiler just uses the object directly, wherever it is.